# Hiding a UIButton from within its own IBAction

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm having a problem with hiding a UIButton in Swift 4.

```
@IBAction func saveTextViewEdits(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (textView.text != String(notes)){
    }
}
```

I want the `if` statement to hide the UIButton `saveTextViewEdits`, but I can't use `saveTextViewEdits.hidden = true` as it says:

> Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'hidden'

How should I do this?

Comment: Your function is called `saveTextViewEdits`, not your button.

Comment: What do I use instead? The identifier?

Comment: I don't think you did enough research on your question. The answer would be everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The property is `isHidden`, not `hidden`.
2. The button is `sender`, not `saveTextViewEdits` (which is the method name).

Your code would be:

```
@IBAction func saveTextViewEdits(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (textView.text != String(notes)){
        sender.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a property object of this button then simply use this:

```
yourButton.isHidden = true
```

and also you can use this into this IBAction

```
@IBAction func saveTextViewEdits(_ sender: UIButton) {
   if (textView.text != String(notes)){
      yourButton.isHidden = true
   }
}
```

And only for this function then you can use :

```
@IBAction func saveTextViewEdits(_ sender: UIButton) {
     if (textView.text != String(notes)){
        sender.isHidden = true
     }
  }
```